# How to convert hexadecimal to base64urlsafe?

Tags: ruby

What would be the best way to convert a hexadecimal value (for instance a SHA-256 digest) into the [base64urlsafe](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/base64/rdoc/Base64.html#method-i-urlsafe_encode64) format?

Example:

```
f("e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855")
# => "47DEQpj8HBSa-_TImW-5JCeuQeRkm5NMpJWZG3hSuFU="
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following should do it:

```
Base64.urlsafe_encode64(Array(hex_string).pack('H*'))
```

The method `urlsafe_encode64` expects binary input, so you need to convert the hex representation to binary first, as shown above.

Answer (score 0):

Use [urlsafe_encode64](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/base64/rdoc/Base64.html#method-i-urlsafe_encode64) method:

```
require 'base64'

# The method urlsafe_encode64 expects binary input, 
# so you need to convert the hex representation to binary
bin_string = [hex_string].pack('H*')

Base64.urlsafe_encode64 bin_string
```